# How to sequence setting of Wix property

Tags: wix

I need to search a path to a file which is part of installation which I am doing like this

```
<Property Id="WEBINSTDIR" >

  <DirectorySearch Path="[INSTALLDIR]" Depth="0" Id="FindInstallDirectory">

    <FileSearch Name="Web.config"/>

  </DirectorySearch>

</Property>
```

Now, this property does not gets initializes, as I am guessing since INSTALL directory is not created when this property is being set, so my question is how to sequence setting of property so that this  WEBINSTDIR gets initialize after actual path INSTALLDIR is created and config files is present.
Thanks
.G

Comment: Are you attempting to determine if this file exists before you start installing files?

Comment: No the idea is to get the file path after this file is created, this property is being initialized before actual path is created that is why it comes out blank, I wanted if I could set this property After the file is created

Comment: This is my current problem as well. I have a property which reads the registries, however, the registry that it needs will be written during the execution sequence and I need to save it in my property so succeeding custom actions can use it.

Comment: were you able to solve this @Great88?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know the path to which the file is installed, then look into the [MSI formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609.aspx) `[#filekey]` or `[!filekey]`. Note that these won't necessarily evaluate correctly if the component containing the file will not be installed, and will never be correct before CostFinalize.

Comment: this is not helping, this returns full path and filename, which I don't need , I just need the Path to file. to be simple I need property to be set after "InstallFinalize".

Comment: If you're looking for post-InstallFinalize, why not just use [DIRPROPERTY] where DIRPROPERTY is the directory name associated with the component containing these files?